# Do photons go through one another?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, photons, superposition, interactions

I just read somewhere that sound could travel through light, and that it can travel even though photons go trought each other. So could anyone explain this to me if they have time?

Comment: Yes, why does that seem to be a problem? Two waves that satisfy a linear wave equation don't interact. Pass two light beams such that they cross paths and you'll see no difference in intensity after the overlapping area

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you name "photon".

Photons are elementary particles in the [standard model,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of zero mass and energy equal to $hν$ where  $ν$ the frequency of the classical electromagnetic wave built up by photons of that frequency.

Photons build up the classical electromagnetic wave, but are not a chunk of the wave.

As particles they interact with charges and even , with very small probability at low frequencies, [with other photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics),  and their interaction is seen in the Feynman diagrams used to model it mathematically . In bulk , the light beams  go through each other *because*   of the tiny probability of photon-photon interaction.

[image]

> A Feynman diagram (box diagram) for photon–photon scattering, one photon scatters from the transient vacuum charge fluctuations of the other

When the frequencies are at energies of gamma rays, the scattering becomes much more probable and the interaction of photon on photon can produce many elementary particles, to the point of a proposal to use  [gamma-gamma colliders](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/beamline/26/1/26-1-kim.pdf) to study general elementary particle interactions.

So photons do not go through each other. Light beams , composed of low energy photons do go through each other.

Comment: Nice, clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm an HS student, so obviously I am answering from a High Schooler perspective.

---

Photons obey wave-particle duality, which means Photons sometimes act as waves and other times act as particles. For a long time, it was believed that Photons were waves. This had to do with the observations from Young's Double-slit experiment. Thomas Young conducted the experiment simply by passing light through two slits close by. If Light were to be made up of particles, it would have passed through the slits like you would expect sand to go through 2 slits. But it did not. This is what Young saw

[image]

This observation resembled that of water waves passing through 2 slits, and drawing the similarities between them, Young concluded that light was a wave. As to why water waves produced that observation, the reason was that peaks and the troughs cancelled each other at some locations (resulting in flat surfaces) while in other places they amplified (resulting in a larger peak). [I would recommend watching this real-life [experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iuv6hY6zsd0) by Veritasium]

[image]

Here's a picture of how water waves behave when passed through 2 slits (if anyone knows how to reduce image size, do let me know)

[image]

But then came new experiments and new observations... The light could eject electrons from the surface of a metallic sample. Kicking electrons out of the atomic orbital would be the more appropriate description if you ask me. But this caused a dilemma. Classical descriptions of a light wave could not produce mathematical equations that were consistent with the experimental observations. The only way to fix this was to assume that light was made up of particles. Einstein won a Nobel Prize in 1921 for this proposal which explained the photoelectric effect. There were other dilemmas too which could only be solved by assuming light was made up of Photons. One such dilemma was the Blackbody radiation which was solved by Max Planck (who was the first one to assume light is a particle).

Of course, now you would say, how is it that light can be both a wave and particle. This created a new dilemma. Some experiments could only be explained if you assumed Light was a wave, like Young's double-slit experiment. Others like the photoelectric effect and the black body radiation could only be explained if you assumed that light has a particle nature. The only way to resolve the dilemma was to accept the idea that light possesses both particle and wave-like properties, in other words, light has a dual wave-particle behaviour. And soon scientists figured out that light showed wave character only when it propagates and particle behaviour only when it interacts with other particles. So, to answer your question in the title, Light behaves like waves when they are propagating which means they can hit each other without bouncing like you would expect tennis balls to

Comment: The wave nature of the photons is in **the probability amplitude** , which is a solution of a wave equation. Light , composed of photons, is also a solution of a different wave equation. The individual photons are not spread out in space as this experiment clearly shows https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/

Comment: @anna v ...Oh so you mean saying light is a wave is different from saying water wave is a wave? Cause in case of photons, the wave nature is in the probability amplitude while in water waves, the wave is due to the water molecules spread in the space?

Comment: Observations in physics that fit what we everyday call a "wave",  are fitted with what are called wave equations, second degree differential equations that have basic solutions sines and cosines, which , with combinations, fit the measurements of waves, water waves, classical electromagnetic waves, sound waves . All these waves have common that they are waves in (x,y,z,t) of energy moving in space. The quantum mechanical probability waves, as with the electrons you show above , and with the photons in the link, show up in accumulations.