# The “Wave Function” of QM and Cosmological Redshift—An Inconsistency In Physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, wavefunction, redshift

Take the archetypal quantum event—the emission of a photon by an atom, and its propagation through space until absorption by another atom.

Assume the emitting atom be one near the edge of our observable universe (that is, one near the “wall of last scattering” of the CMB), and the absorbing atom to be one in a detector on earth at the south pole. QM postulates that every particle has also a wave characteristic (the “wave-particle duality”), and, therefore, this photon during propagation will have wave characteristics.

I have been informed by the most eminent physicists that in the mathematics of QM, the propagation of the photon from the source of emission is described as occurring in spherical waves, representing all possible outcomes, all of which are said to be (in one of the fundamental postulates of QM) in “superposition” with one another, until the moment of detection, when all of the waves in all directions “collapse” to a single point in space (to the place of the observation, I suppose, in this case the detector at the south pole).

Until observation, the possible outcomes include (among an infinity of others) the absorption by an atom at an equal distance in the opposite direction, i.e., the waves propagate a distance twice the radius of the observable universe, with the actual observation of the photon at the south pole, therefore, resulting in what one might thus call the “ultimate” in wave collapse—instantaneously across a distance equal to the the entire diameter of the known universe. (A postulate which poses its own questions, of significance equal to, but separate from the one being presently considered). One does not conceive of these waves as representing the electromagnetic energy of this single photon, distributed over the entire surface of this universe-wide sphere, and QM does not so postulate, saying nothing about its location until detected.

The waves associated with the different possible outcomes, so physicists postulate, may interfere with one another (as in the two slit experiment), generating different probabilities of observation in different places, say in different directions. I take these waves to be equivalent to the waves of the Schrodinger wave function, although he was talking about the waves associated with an electron within an atom, and the probability of detecting it at any particular place. But it would seem that in QM the waves of the electron and those of the photon occupy mathematically similar roles: furnishing the probabilities of detection, for either, at particular points in space.

Now, probabilities, as a mathematical concept, are pure numbers: anything from zero to one. And they are nothing more than pure numbers. (In QM the probabilities are the square of the wave amplitudes at any point, so the amplitudes themselves, of the waves, being the square roots of those probabilities, which are pure numbers, must therefore also be pure numbers). It would be sheer linguistic nonsense to assert that pure numbers (fluctuating in value at any one place) could move from place to place in space—to the extent that no one could have any understanding of what it could possibly mean—that is, it would be unintelligible. Numbers don't move, or go places. This would lead one to conclude that the waves of QM at issue here have no physical existence. That is, they are non-physical. That is, they exist only in the mind of the physicist-mathematician, or on the paper he has written them on, in mathematical form. And they do not exist in space as objects or entities occupying actual space.

This conclusion seems strongly supported by the fact that, in our example, if the waves were, instead, “physical,” then all of the waves, spread out over a sphere whose diameter equals that of the entire known universe, would have to somehow move (“collapse”) instantaneously to the point of detection—a highly problematic postulate, to say the least.

On the other hand, the red shift of light from the expanding universe is dependent on the opposite supposition: that the waves have a physical existence, occupying actual physical space. The quintessential example is a CMB photon much like the photon we set out to consider in the example: the light of a CMB photon detected at the south pole originated, so the theory goes, at very high energy, let us say as a gamma ray. We supposed the photon of our example to be also a gamma ray emitted by an atom near the CMB photon's source. The explanation: the length of its waves (“wavelength”) are so short that many millions fit in the distance of a centimeter. But, during its traverse across the universe from at or near the “wall of last scattering,” until its detection, the space it occupies (or which its waves occupy) expands, and, with it, the waves representing the propagation of that photon, also stretch or expand. That is, they get longer. By the time they arrive at the south pole, they are microwaves, and each wavelength is now about 2 mm, or about 5 per centimeter. The whole explanation would therefore seem to require a very real, by which I mean “physical,” existence of the waves to make any sense, that is, in order for it to actually furnish the explanation it purports to offer.

(Cosmological expansion of the universe is a part of the theory of Relativity, developed by Einstein, using Maxwell's theory of light, which is a classical theory of a fluctuating values (waves) at a point in an electromagnetic field at successive times, and is not based on QM. The question, therefore, might be asked if the light waves explained as red-shifted by the expansion of the universe (discovered much later) are actually equivalent to the waves of QM that are presently under consideration. Is the comparison of apples to oranges? Physicists are in the habit of saying that different laws govern physical reality at different scales, from the largest to smallest. But there are several grounds for concluding that the waves we are considering are all equivalent and identical, and that the question posed may not be avoided on that ground. First, the wave mathematics of the Maxwell wave theory of light was lifted, lock, stock, and barrel, and transplanted wholesale into QM in the exact same mathematical form, with exactly corresponding waves. And Max Born received his Nobel Prize for postulating that those waves, in Schrodinger's use of them, represent the “superposed” possible outcomes, and that their amplitudes dictate their respective probabilities (when squared). That is, that the waves taken from Maxwell's theory were now said to be “waves” of pure numbers. Second, in QM physicists universally speak of the “wavelength” of every photon (from gamma ray and x-ray photons down to visible light photons and beyond); and the wavelength of any one of them corresponds exactly with the wavelength of the corresponding light in the Maxwell theory, because it is directly derived from, or lifted from, that wavelength in that theory. And physicists universally speak of the exceedingly short wavelength of a single gamma ray photon being stretched to the long wavelength of a CMB photon by cosmological expansion, just as the waves of Maxwell's theory are treated in the cosmological expansion of General Relativity. Finally, the waves analyzed to explain the two slit experiment by either the Maxwell theory or the QM theory are the exact same waves, mathematically, with the exact same wavelengths. And, in the QM theory's explanation of that experiment, the waves associated with each single photon (such as in our example) are the ones that are said to interfere with others of the same individual photon (“self-interference”), to yield the varying “probabilities”of its detection at particular places. It would therefore seem that the waves of both theories are mathematically the same. Probabilities are the only thing that QM ever predicts, and those probabilities always remain pure numbers, as we have seen, numbers that “exist” only in the mind of humans. And so the question remains whether the explanation, in QM, of the propagation of the photon in spherical waves, being pure numbers and necessarily non-physical, is consistent with the explanation of the wavelength of the CMB having been stretched, along with the space itself which it occupies, due to cosmological expansion—an explanation which, to make any sense at all, requires the postulate that they are physical entities spread out over that space. The question does not go away. The single photon of our question is therefore required, by the theory of cosmological expansion, to be a physical entity stretched out over space as it travels, at the same time its waves are required by QM to be pure numbers, which cannot be).

Are both of these views of what physicists assert (and their math) accurate portrayals of what they actually say, and of its implications? If not, what is the flaw in the reasoning? And if they are accurate, why is this not an inconsistency in the basic fabric of physics?

Finally, if the analysis is accurate, is this an inconsistency forming part of the basis on which physicists can say—as they universally do—that the the two theories, QM and General Relativity, are fundamentally incompatible?

**Edited, by addition, in response to answer of @anna v**:

The citation to the two slit experiment, done one photon at a time, seems for the purpose of illustrating the wave characteristic of the particle, but that was already clearly assumed in the question, so pointing that out, as well as the fact that it is observed as a “dot” (i.e., a particle), seems not to reach the actual question posed.

The reference to self-interference was not meant to suggest it would be observed, which obviously it is not, but to demonstrate that the wave characteristic applies to each individual photon. Self-interference of the waves of each photon is clearly shown by the fact that running the experiment one photon at a time, say, one per day, will produce exactly the same pattern in the ensemble which your illustration shows. Self-interference of the waves of an individual photon is a bedrock of QM, as demonstrated by Dirac (1930), discussing one in an interferometer:

“If the two components are now made to interfere, we should require a photon in one component to be able to interfere with one in the other. Sometimes these two photons would have to annihilate one another and other times they would have to produce four photons. This would contradict the conservation of energy. The new theory, which connects the wave function with probabilities for one photon, gets over the difficulty by making each photon go partly into each of the two components. Each photon then interferes only with itself. Interference between two different photons never occurs.”

Your assertion that it is the “accumulations” that show the wave nature in the interference pattern, is correct, as is your statement that “It is the probability of a photon to hit the (x,y) of the detector that carries the wave nature, not the individual photon itself,” (correct, sort of, except for the last phrase). You make a similar statement in your penultimate paragraph with respect to electrons in two slit experiments. The individual photon has to have waves, in order to interfere with itself. If you mean to imply that only the “ensemble” of all the photons possesses a  wave nature, as a sort of meta-characteristic of the entire group, and not of each individual photon, your statements would be in direct conflict with Dirac's.

The same analysis applies to an assertion in the penultimate paragraph of your answer. You correctly state, first, that “The particles . . . [photons] are classical point like particles when detected individually.” Certainly they are, and the question assumed that; it is the other half of the wave-particle duality. But you go on to say that photons interact with each other: “and their interactions [i.e., those of the photons] give probability distributions that have wave properties.”

That is clearly contradicted by Dirac. The photons do not interact with each other to produce the waves; in his statement of the theory of interference they do not interact at all, so there are no interactions between photons to serve that function. The particles, the photons, already have wave characteristics, and those are the waves that dictate the probability distributions of all possible outcomes.

The thrust of this portion of your answer, which appears to attempt to avoid the question as ill-posed, by asserting that there is no wave characteristic to an individual photon (thereby removing one of its premises), is therefore unconvincing.

On the other hand, if, by associating “the wave nature” only with “the probability” of a hit anywhere, you would at least seem to be agreeing with my assertion that the waves (whether you agree they are “carried by” the individual photon or not), cannot be “physical” in any meaningful sense, and that they are pure numbers, existing only in the mind of humans. That would be a concession which, once applied to the individual photon, as per Dirac, would restore the premise completely: In QM the individual photon has wave characteristics, and the waves cannot be considered physical entities occupying space.

Turning to redshift, the fact that the actual means used by astronomers to measure it is, as you point out, that of spectral lines shifting from nearer the blue end of the visible spectrum towards the red end does not change the fact that in the theory, the gamma ray wavelength is lengthened as a result of cosmological expansion, and it expands along with the space it is traversing. Nor does the method of measuring it negate the fact that in the theory of cosmological expansion, the wavelength of what started as a gamma ray, in the example, has, in the course of cosmological expansion, transitioned through the entire spectrum to a much longer wavelength of the CMB. It is simply the evidence of  it. Presumably an observer much closer to the source of emission, at a much earlier time, would have seen it as visible light; after further expansion, we “see” (detect) it as the CMB in the microwave range. But in the theory, we each see whatever redshift we observe, because of the association of the wavelength of the photon with the actual physical space it traverses, and their expansion together. The wavelength of the individual photon, therefore, in the explanation of cosmological redshift, had to have a physical character to expand with the space it is traversing.

Therefore, the thrust of this portion of your answer, which appears to attempt to avoid the question posed, by focusing on methods, as if to imply that the theory of cosmological expansion does not depend on a wavelength of the photon as it passes through space (and thereby removing the other premise of the question), is equally unconvincing. Whatever the spectral line is measured at, its redshifted light, that is, the wavelength of its light, has been stretched with cosmological expansion. The theory therefore postulates a wavelength of the photon with a physical existence spread out over space.

With respect to my assertion that “the theory of cosmological expansion” requires the single photon “to be a physical entity stretched out over space,” you add: “This is wrong. The single photon is a single photon propagating in straight lines from the star of its origin . . . .” And further: “The individual photon is a particle following a straight/geodesic line until it interacts with something.”

Let me first say I personally could not agree more (except for the first sentence). In fact the origin of this entire question can be traced back to my reading exactly that in Einstein's 1917 seminal and landmark article (the basis for the laser), which is still cited today and has never been repudiated, even by those who disagreed with him, such as Bohr, Born, and Pauli (1949), who all cite it in their tributes to Einstein, with apparent approval. Speaking of the elemental process which is described in the example in my original question, Einstein wrote, in the conclusions of this paper, that “We can thus consider the following as rather certainly proved”:

“If the molecule undergoes a loss of energy of magnitude hν without external influence, by emitting this energy in the form of radiation (spontaneous emission), this process is also a directed one. There is no emission in spherical waves.”

In his introduction to the paper Einstein had posed the question: “does the molecule receive an impulse when it absorbs or emits the energy ε?” and poses two possible hypotheses: unidirectional emission, and an “isotropic process, for instance, in the form of spherical waves,” and states that the “main result” of the paper is that: “It now turns out that we arrive at a consistent theory only, if we assume each elementary process to be completely directional.” (Italics in original).

Yet, in pointing these statements out to multiple physicists, I have not found a single one who had actually ever read this article, and when I have quoted it, they have been skeptical whether his article actually says what I have just quoted (until reading it themselves). Then, after hearing physicist after physicist in lectures speak as if the propagation were spherical, I began an experiment of asking this question:

In the sequence (photon emission/propagation/detection) does the math of quantum mechanics describe the photon's propagation through space as spherical; in a straight line; or the question is based on incorrect assumptions or otherwise ill-conceived?

The results were quite uniform: “spherical,” (with elaboration, by some). One of them, a professed string theorist, and head of a distinguished physics institute at a major university (whom I shall not identify because he was not writing for publication) wrote, verbatim:

“His concern [Einstein's] is that the particle cannot truly be in a spherical wave since its emitted momentum must point in some particular direction.  Yet also the emission process may (for suitable systems) be spherically symmetric, in which case the emission must be in a spherical wave.  But the two are reconciled by the fact that the spherical wave can be made up out of a superposition of directed (plane) waves in all directions.”

Another, who has worked for decades as an experimenter at a major National Laboratory that houses the brightest light on the planet, doing actual experiments with it, gave essentially the same answer. As did numerous others. My “physicist experiment” is now completed, with uniformly consistent outcomes. As a result, I take it as canonical in QM, today, that the propagation of a single photon, as in the example, is in the form of spherical waves, as stated in the original question.

So it does not seem possible to eliminate this premise of the question on the basis you have proposed, of straight line propagation, notwithstanding Einstein's view.

Insofar as your answer appears to portray the question as flawed or ill-conceived for having faulty premises, it is unconvincing, when compared with contrary statements that physicists uniformly say in explaining their work, and even in their academic articles, as Dirac's. In my judgment it therefore fails to fairly meet and answer the main question posed.

You do directly answer the last question, for which I thank you, but, since you support it by stating that photons interact with other photons (in contradiction to Dirac), I have to doubt whether the reason you give is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Finally, the waves analyzed to explain the two slit experiment by either the Maxwell theory or the QM theory are the exact same waves, mathematically, with the exact same wavelengths. And, in the QM theory's explanation of that experiment, the waves associated with each single photon (such as in our example) are the ones that are said to interfere with others of the same individual photon (“self-interference”), to yield the varying “probabilities”of its detection at particular places

Here is the [double slit experiment one photon at a time :](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/)

[image: sinlfot]

> Single-photon camera recording of photons from a double slit illuminated by very weak laser light. Left to right: single frame, superposition of 200, 1’000, and 500’000 frames.

This basic experiment shows that the individual photons have a particle footprint on the screen, the accumulations shows the wave nature in the interference pattern. It is the **probability** of a photon to hit the (x,y) of the detector that carries the wave nature , not the individual photon itself. This probability depends on the boundary values and limits of the experiment "photons hitting double slits given distance apart and given width". The "self interference" is an effort to describe in words what mathematics gives clearly. The experiment shows no self interference, each photon is a dot.

A photon emitted by an atom at the beginning of the cosmic microwave background decoupling, is characterized by the spectrum of that specific atom, a collection of similar atomic emissions arriving at a detector on earth [show the redshift of the spectrum,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/redshf.html) and special relativity mathematics allows to calculate how much energy the photons have lost.

> The single photon of our question is therefore required, by the theory of cosmological expansion,

This is wrong. The single photon is a single photon propagating in straight lines from the star of its origin, or from the [decoupling from the primordial](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/wctransp.html) plasma in the Big Bang model.

> to be a physical entity stretched out over space as it travels, at the same time its waves are required by QM to be pure numbers, which cannot be).

The individual photon is a particle  following a straight/geodesic line until it interacts with something ( as the screen of our detectors).

> Finally, if the analysis is accurate, is this an inconsistency forming part of the basis on which physicists can say—as they universally do—that the the two theories, QM and General Relativity, are fundamentally incompatible?

No , this is not the reason.

The reason is not this vague  wave particle duality expanded to cosmic proportions. The particles , (and photons are particles in the standard model),  are classical point like particles when detected individually and particle-particle  interactions  give **probability distributions that have wave properties**.(Single electron double slit experiments also show in the accumulation the wave nature of the probability distribution)

QM and GR have yet to be mathematically in one definite form, although effective quantization of gravity models are successful in fitting a number of observations,because it is a hard mathematical problem still being researched theoretically.

Comment: @ anna v. Just how do those waveless photons interact with each other to produce the probabily which you say "carries the wave nature"? See my edit re statements of prominent physicists which seem directly contradictory to a number of yours.

Comment: You are misinterpreting my statement. The single photons interact with the environment they find. If you are able to understand experiments, the single photon experiment shown above, the time delay between photons is irrelevant to the plots, you could wait a year for each photon from the laser ( same laser same slits same everything except time of shot) and the plot would be the same. Dirac a great mind, is not a pope,  no physicist no matter how great, is a pope, i.e. without errors or misleading proposals sometime.

Comment: As a clarifictation, photons do have a small probability of interacting with each other successfully modeled mathematically in field theory, see my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/684109/do-photons-go-through-one-another/684115#684115

Comment: How do your waveless photons ("not the individual photon") interact to produce the probabily you say "carries the wave nature"? See my edit of Q re statements of eminent physicists which are directly contrary to a number of yours. The wave particle duality of every particle is a fundamental postulate of QM; my treatment of it may be conceptual, not quantative; but it is  as clear as its definition by Bohr-not vague. Does it disappear when photons travel great distances? No "vague" cosmic proportions here; only a great distance & long time for one photon to experience redshift.

Comment: Did not see your response until now. Dirac not a pope of physics, for sure. But a lecturer on quantum computing has told me the same thing: "each photon interferes only with itself." As a non-physicist I do not formulate theories, only listen carefully to what physicists say (and write), and record it. As I did with the many who have told me the propagation of a single photon is in spherical waves. I do not think I have misinterpreted your clear statements. Only compared them to others. What else is a lay person to do? And ask questions, hoping for a clear answer.

Comment: I think we should stop here. Photons and electrons etc are quantum entities in the standard model of particle physics, and I will not repeat what the mainstream model for particles is, and the wave-particle duality at present day mainstream physics is the duality I explained, particle like when interacting, wave function predicting the probability of interaction as in the experiment above. It is not a postulate per se, it comes out of the wavefunction postulate and the Feynman diagrams used for computing interactions. Incidentally the old-before-quantum-field-theory observations can be derived